# I would want to prevent deletion of an entity if its associated with a different entity

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I would want to prevent deletion of an entity if its associated with a different entity in the user interface.

```
class foo 
  belongs_to bar

class bar
```

While fetching /foos (i.e. a list of Foo objects), we would like to somehow show the count of bar(s) for each foo, the user interface could use this as an indication to avoid deletion for Bar entities grater zero

Answer (score 1):

To prevent deletion of one entity which is associated with another entity can be done using **soft delete**. In rails, it can be achieved using **acts_as_paranoid gem**.

https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is wrong, what you're trying to say is the following:

```
class foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars
end

class bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

If this is the case, then you'll need to implement a [counter cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to).

Your code will then become:

```
class bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo, counter_cache: true
end
```

And you should add to `foo` a column called `bars_count`;

Now, whenever you create a new foo, it will automatically increase `bars_count`; and of course, decrease it when you delete a foo.